# fragment created twice on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation

I know this question has been asked, but I haven't succeeded with the answers.

I have a fragment with a recycler view in it. I have a button which can show and hide this fragment. This all works fine until the orietation of the screen is changed. Then the fragment is recreated, and the one on top is shown and hidden, but there is one behind which stays there.

I understand I need to use

```
if (savedInstanceState == null)
```

somewhere, but cannot manage to succeed where. Thanks very much, 
Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    recyclerViewFragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();

    FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    trans.add(R.id.recycle_view_container, recyclerViewFragment, RECYCLER_FRAGMENT);
    trans.commit();
    trans.show(recyclerViewFragment);

    Button showHideButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_show_hide);
    showHideButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showHideFragment(recyclerViewFragment);
        }
    });
    showHideButton.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);

}

public void showHideFragment(final Fragment fragment){

    FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    trans.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left , android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    if (fragment.isHidden()) {
        trans.show(fragment);
        Log.d("hidden","Show");
    } else {
        trans.hide(fragment);
        Log.d("Shown","Hide");
    }

    trans.commit();
}
```

Thanks very much guys!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest make some changes to your code
I suppose that RECYCLER_FRAGMENT is a constant that contains a tag used to mark your fragment

```
 RecyclerViewFragment recyclerViewFragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        recyclerViewFragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();

        FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.add(R.id.recycle_view_container, recyclerViewFragment, RECYCLER_FRAGMENT);
        trans.commit();
    }else{
        recyclerViewFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(RECYCLER_FRAGMENT);
        if(savedInstanceState.getString("vi").equals("hid")){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(recyclerViewFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    Button showHideButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_show_hide);
    showHideButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            if (fragment.isVisible()) {
                manager.beginTransaction().hide(recyclerViewFragment).commit();
            } else {
                manager.beginTransaction().show(recyclerViewFragment).commit();
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if(recyclerViewFragment.isVisible() == true){
        outState.putString("vi","vis");
    }else{
        outState.putString("vi", "hid");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. Is there anything wrong with the answer below to just change add to replace?

Comment: i don't think that using replace works .I'm not sure but if you hide the fragment then rotate the screen I think the fragment will appear without pressing the button

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
trans.add(R.id.recycle_view_container, recyclerViewFragment, RECYCLER_FRAGMENT);
```

try this:

```
trans.replace(R.id.recycle_view_container, recyclerViewFragment, RECYCLER_FRAGMENT);
```

The name is misleading. `Replace` actually works as add also, if the first time. What is happening is that when your activity rotate, `onCreate()` is called again so you are adding the same fragment on top of the existing one

Comment: Thank you, It saved me a day!